# Is $S$ convergent or divergent?

Tags: real-analysis

> Is   $$S=\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(\log n)^{\log n}}$$ convergent  or divergent?

My attempt :  $(\log n)^{\log n} = \exp((\log \log n)^2) \le \exp(((\log n)^{1/2})^2) = n$ for $n \ge N_0$, so $$\sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac 1 {(\log n)^{ \log n}} \ge C + \sum_{n=N_0}^\infty \frac 1 n = \infty$$

so it  is divergent

Is its true ?